# Regex CamelCase filename, but also remove extension

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I have this regex for use in a Sublime Text snippet:

`${TM_FILENAME/(^|-|\.)(?!ts)(.?)|/\U\2\E/g}`

But it's mainly about this part: `(^|-|\.)(?!ts)(.?)` (https://regex101.com/r/zgiQZ0/1)

What I want is convert `app-user-icon.component.ts` into `AppUserComponent`

I got this far, and get `AppUserIconComponent.ts`

What I need is instead of ignoring (`(?!ts)`) it I need to filter it out/remove the `.ts` part.

I'm having trouble with what to do with this part: `|/\U\2\E/g`, because this is what is converting it to Caps. And any online regex parser doesn't accept it (see: https://regex101.com/r/zgiQZ0/2).
Also I'm not sure If I should regex the result after it's capitalized.

Removing the `.ts` part worked in another part of the snippet: `(.*)[.](.*)` not sure where to put that in this one expression though.

(Here is the whole snippet if you're interested:)

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '${TM_FILENAME/(.*)(.component)[.](.*)/$1/g}',
  templateUrl: '${TM_FILENAME/(.*)[.](.*)/$1/g}.html'
})
export class ${TM_FILENAME/(^|-|\.)(?!ts)(.?)|/\U\2\E/g} {
  constructor() {}
  $0
}]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>ng2-component</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.ts,source.tsx,source.js</scope>
  <description>Angular 2 Component Snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '${TM_FILENAME/(.*)(.component)[.](.*)/$1/g}',
  templateUrl: '${TM_FILENAME/(.*)[.](.*)/$1/g}.html'
})
export class ${TM_FILENAME/(?:\.ts$)|(?:^|-|\.)(.)/\u\1/g} {
  constructor() {}
  $0
}]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>ng2-component</tabTrigger>
  <scope>source.ts,source.tsx,source.js</scope>
  <description>Angular 2 Component Snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

Where the regex is:

- `(?:\.ts$)` not capturing group to match `.ts` at the end of the filename
- `|` or
- `(?:^|-|\.)` non capturing group to match the start of the filename, a `-` or `.` character, followed by

  - `(.)` capture any single character into capture group 1
- `/` begin replacement

  - `\u` upper case the next character
  - `\1` the character that was captured earlier into capture group 1
- `/` end of replacement
- `g` global flag to match more than once